# Discord Bot sending messages if function is true

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Thats my function what checks broadcast

```
def broadcast1():
    if 'isLiveBroadcast' in contents:
        return True
```

And thats my function what must send messages to specific text channel about broadcast

```
@bot.event
async def broadcast2(broadcast1):
    if broadcast1 is True:
        channel = bot.get_channel(1067083439263727646)
        await channel.send('ЖАБА СТРИМИТ')
```

I have been written two functions which must work together and sends messages in text channel when broadcast is live but they dont work

No Errors, just doesnt working

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Did you mean to use `broadcast1()`?

Comment: i am new in creating discord bots and idk how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a few fundamental issues with your code and the program logic.

Firstly, `@bot.event` is typically used for registering "listeners" to Discord events. There is no `broadcast2` event to listen out for. Therefore, the function will *never* be executed. You can look at the [event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference) here and see all the events that we can respond/react to.

Secondly, as the commenter above as pointed out, you've not actually invoked the function. Saying `if broadcast1` is True`doesn't work how you think it works. By itself,`broadcast1`is a function, and therefore`broadcast1`is a function object. It will never equal True; so event if we were listening for the right event, it would never do what you want it do anyways. What we _should_ be doing, is actually invoked the function:`broadcast1()`. This means the function and the code gets run. There's lots of [tutorials online](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) about how functions in python work. Linked is just one example.

Thirdly, in the `broadcast1` channel, you're checking if "isLiveBroadcast" is in `contents`. What contents? Where is that defined? You might need to rethink that as well.

All in all, you should probably look at following a Python basics course and then following some tutorials for putting together Discord bots. [The docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) are a good place to start - trying following the quickstart stuff and then adapting as you go along.

Comment: thanks! I didnt post a whole code, i know that contents is defined. broadcast1() works but yep, i need to watch tutorials and read docs firstly to do what i want